# Graph theory question, probably with Ramsey's theorem?

Tags: graph-theory

We have a club with $\frac{s(s+1)}{2}$ people, and we know that no matter how we choose $3$ of them, there are at least $2$ of them, who know each other.

Prove, that if this is true, then we can always choose $s$ people, where all of them know each other.
In graph language, we have a graph with $\frac{s(s+1)}{2}$ vertices, and we draw edges if $2$ people know each other. No matter how we choose $3$ vertices, we always find at least $1$ edge. Prove, that this graph has $K_s$ in it($s$ vertices with all possible edges drawn).

I tried to prove this in different ways, but just can't conclude why is it true, maybe it can be solved with Ramsey's theoerem?

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, you want to colour edges in your given graph by blue, and all non-edges by red. This gives a red-blue colouring of the edges of $K_{{s+1\choose 2}}.$

Really, the main point is to show that that $R(3,s)\leq {s+1\choose 2}$, where $R(3,s)$ is the smallest $n$ so that any red-blue colouring of the edges of $K_n$ has either a red $K_3$ or a blue $K_s$. Since you are given that your graph has no red $K_3$, you can conclude that it has a blue $K_s$.

To show that upper bound, use induction and the inequality $$R(r, s) \leq R(r − 1, s) + R(r, s − 1)$$ for all $r,s$. Also, notice that $R(2,s)=s$.